# android adb failed connecting after reboot without HDMI monitor connected

Tags: android, linux, adb

Can any please advise? I met this problem on wifi that I can't connect it without having my board connected with a HDMI monitor. Which is preventing my adb automatically work via wifi.

I always get this error message "wi-fi service is not ready"

I want a set up at my lab, with a device automatically connected online, when I need reboot the system, I just do `adb reboot` from someone's laptop in my local network, then after 5 seconds, I shall be able to `adb connect ip:5555`

I am developping kernel and HAL software on SDM845 dragon board, running androidS, Linux version 5.9.0, bellow are some details:

```
ro.build.version.sdk=29
ro.build.version.codename=S
ro.product.system.device=db845c
Linux version 5.9.0-rc8-mainline-00160-g90cf4b67bfe5-dirty
```

I debug a lot on device drivers, so it happens frequently either I make kernel crashes to reboot or I reboot manually.

It is a headache thing that, every time I have to manually connect both USB and HDMI cable to the hardware to start my wifi service to connect local network.

```
 --------------------------------                    --------------------
| SDM845 runs AOSP with ADB server|  --connects --> |    jenkins server  |
 --------------------------------                    --------------------
                                       connects-->  | another developer PC |
                                                     ----------------------
```

Bellow commands are used for connecting adb to the server

```
// first I connect adb via USB cable after HDMI connected with android
// before this I have got my wifi password configured by UI settings
adb root
adb shell
svc wifi enable
ifconfig wlan0 // now I get my ip address as 192.168.72.166
exit from adb shell
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.72.166 // now I get my adb connect through the air
```

I wish to have everything automatic, It is clear that wifi service does not start before HDMI connected, I just dont know how to make it work! But I failed after searching by google 99 usless articles, can anyone please advice any clue?

if I dont connect HDMI to my board, I always get error like Wi-fi service is not ready.
I checked kernel log with `dmesg | tail -80 | grep wifi`, here is what I found.

```
[ 7777.677237] init: starting service 'wificond'...
[ 7782.144809] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'wificond' (pid 16395) process group...
[ 7782.365746] init: Service 'wificond' (pid 16395) received signal 9
[ 7782.735338] init: starting service 'wificond'...
```

[image]